# How to get the all the lists of preimages of a surjective map is the image is given?

Tags: list-manipulation, mapthread

Firstly, I want to construct a map with the preimage `{{5}, {4, 3}, {4, 2}, {3, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 1}, {2, 1}}` and the image `{1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4}` correspondingly. So as you can see it's a surjective map.

Then, I hope to have a function that if we input `{1,2,3}`,

I will get all possible combinations of their corresponding preimages, i.e. `{{5}, {4, 2}, {2, 2, 1}}, {{5}, {3, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 1}}, {{4, 3}, {4, 2}, {2, 2, 1}}, {{4, 3}, {3, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 1}}`.

The order of the lists is not important, but inside each list, the order should be kept.

Could you offer me some help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ClearAll[f]
f[pi_, im_] := Tuples @* Map[GroupBy[AssociationThread[pi, im]] @ pi]
```

***Examples:***

```
pimg = {{5}, {4, 3}, {4, 2}, {3, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 1}, {2, 1}};
img = {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4};

f[pimg , img] @ {1, 2, 3}
```

> ```
>  {{{5}, {4, 2}, {2, 2, 1}}, 
>   {{5}, {3, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 1}},
>   {{4, 3}, {4, 2}, {2, 2, 1}}, 
>   {{4, 3}, {3, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 1}}}
> ```

```
f[pimg , img] @ {1, 2}
```

> ```
> {{{5}, {4, 2}}, 
>  {{5}, {3, 2, 1}},
>  {{4, 3}, {4, 2}}, 
>  {{4, 3}, {3, 2, 1}}}
> ```

```
f[pimg , img] @ {3, 2}
```

> ```
> {{{2, 2, 1}, {4, 2}}, 
>  {{2, 2, 1}, {3, 2, 1}}}
> ```

Alternatively, you can construct a list of `Association`s from `pimg` and `img` and use [`Merge`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Merge.html):

```
ClearAll[g]
g[pi_, im_] := Tuples @* Map[Merge[Identity][Association /@ Thread[im -> pi]]]

g[pimg, img] == f[pimg, img]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Answer (score 3):

One way to represent the function, call it `map`, is like this

```
domain = {{5}, {4, 3}, {4, 2}, {3, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 1}, {2, 1}};
image = {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4};

map = Transpose[{domain, image}];
```

To find the preimage of a subset, `img`, of the image set, do this

```
img = {1, 2, 3};
preimage = First /@ Select[map, MemberQ[img, Last[#]] &] // DeleteDuplicates

{{5}, {4, 3}, {4, 2}, {3, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 1}}
```

or this

```
preimage = Select[map, MemberQ[img, Last[#]] &] // Transpose // First // Union

{{5}, {4, 2}, {4, 3}, {2, 2, 1}, {3, 2, 1}}
```

Note that using `DeleteDuplicates` as in the first example gives an unsorted preimage and using `Union` as in the second example gives a sorted preimage.

Another way to define the mapping is with an association.  Finding the preimage is then a matter of using `Position` to find the "keys" of the association that map to the "values" in the image, like this

```
map2 = Association[Rule @@@ map];
keys = Position[map2, #] & /@ img // Flatten;
preimage = keys /. Key -> Identity

{{5}, {4, 3}, {4, 2}, {3, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 1}}
```

Answer (score 2):

make a defaultdict

```
ass=AssociationMap[Function[x,{}] , {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4}];
```

groupby it

```
MapThread[AppendTo[ass[#1],#2]&,
{
{1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4},
{{5}, {4, 3}, {4, 2}, {3, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 1}, {2, 1}}
}
];
```

then

```
Tuples[ass/@{1,2,3}]
```

will give us all we need,